# No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator on running Cordova run android on Mac to an Android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Cordova and want to debug the app on my Android device.
When I am plugging the device I have to accept MTP permission - I did so.
I also enabled developer USB mode in the device settings.

When I run the next command:

```
cordova run android
```

The app is getting installed in the device in 50% success rate.
I don't know why, but sometimes its just working and the app pops up and sometimes its just not working.

I have tried to reconnect the USB, after 10 times of doing so, it works and then again start to get corrupt.

It's a new brand original samsung cable that I am using.
I am using Android file transfer in my Mac in order to make this working (without this, it does not working at all).

I have two questions, one related to Cordova and one related to the Android device USB:

1. How to make the device reachable for the Mac so I can transfer data without interruptions?
2. Is there any option to tell Cordova to build **WIRELESS**? I know it's possible using Ionic with --livereload flag. However I don't use Ionic with this project.

I have tried to do `cordova run android -- --live-reload` (in the cordova project) but this doesn't really doing something - it does not response when there is change in the build or something.

Comment: I am also having this issue. It is frustrating because adb shows that the device is attached and authenticated. Cordova just simply... fails to deploy? It's about 50% for me. I'm also on a Mac.

Comment: Try to upgrade to the latest version of Cordova, have at least Android 10 and verify that your cable has a good fit. You also may introduce a service that will first check if there any response from add devices and only then it will deploy, instead of launching the very annoying and slow Android Simulator

Answer (score 1):

You already enable development mode. You are facing 50% success rate. I didnt get your main issue.

I have suggestion and step which you can follow to make work as I always do.

Step 1) Enable development mode

Step 2) Authenticated the connect device.
   - When you connect first you will get authentication confirmation in device.

Step 3) Check connected or not(most recommend command when you connect, just cross chekc and sometime this command properly your device by starting adb server which is required to run application in android)

```
adb devices
```

(Open terminal and typpe this command)

Note : Make sure connected device show in terminal and authenticated.